# Logstash parse multiple instances of the same word into Elasticsearch Array

Tags: parsing, elasticsearch, logstash

I am trying to extract the following from a log line into 2 different array fields

> 03/07/2014 13:29:43.103 INFO NUM**0000001**DOS**0000001-000000001** TDKIIDKSSS NUM**0000002**DOS**0000002-000000001** TDKIIDKSSS NUM**0000003**DOS**0000003-000000001** TTDKIIDKSSS NUM**0000004**DOS**0000004-000000001** TDKIIDKSSS NUM**0000005**DOS**0000005-000000001** TDKIIDKSSS

My issue is that from my experience, grok works only on fixed patterns. I am trying to extract the above numbers from different log lines that would have NUM and DOS repeated ranging for 2 times or 100 times.

Is there a way to get multiple repetitions and put them in an array using logstash for elasticsearch to store?

Answer (score 1):

I think your best shot with these log lines is the following approach :

```
filter{
  mutate{
    gsub=>["message","NUM\*(?:[0-9]+)\*DOS\*"," ","message","[*|-]"," "]
  }
  extractnumbers{}
}
```

The above will extract NUM & DOS numbers from the message field, it will put **NUM in an odd values (int1,int3,...)**, & **DOS in an even ones (int2,int4...)**. Be aware that **any leading zero will be removed from the values ( 00001 => 1 )**.
The output will be the following for your log :

```
# leaing zeros will be removed
int1=>1, #NUM
int2=>1, #DOS
int3=>2, #NUM
int4=>1, #DOS
int5=>3,
int6=>1,
int7=>4,
int8=>1,
int9=>5,
int10=>1
```

I hope this help :) .